Show that the intersection of planes $(VMC),(VNA),(VPB)$ is line if and only if the pyramid has $2$ lateral sides congruent.
The problem
Let the triangular pyramid $VABC$ with the base the equilateral triangle $ABC$. Let $VM \perp AB, VN\perp BC, VP\perp AC$, where the points $M,N,P \in$ the segments $[AB],[BC],[CA]$.
Show that the intersection of planes $(VMC),(VNA),(VPB)$ is the line if and only if the pyramid has $2$ lateral sides congruent.
my idea
drawing

First case: We know that pyramid $VABC$ has $2$ congruent lateral sides. We show that the intersection of the planes is a line.
We can observe that the planes have all in common point $V$, we need to find another point that $\in$ all of these planes to shore that the intersection is a line.
I let $VB=VC=> N$ is the midpoint of BC
We can show that $\triangle VAB$ is congruent with $\triangle VAC$ so $VM=VP$ because they are both heights of those triangles this means we also have $PC=MB$ and $AP=AM$
We can observe that $\frac{NC*MB*AP}{BN*MA*PC}=1$ and by the reciprocal of the theorem of Ceva we get that $AN, BP, MC$ intersect in a point let it be $O$. Because $AN,BP,MC \in(VNA),(VPB),$
respectively $(VMC)$   We found the other point we were looking at.
$V,O\in (VMC),(VNA),(VPB)$ so the intersection of $(VMC),(VNA),(VPB)$  is the line $VO$.
I don't know what to do for the other case where We show that pyramid $VABC$ has $2$ lateral sides congruent. We understand that the intersection of the planes is a line.
I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Where did this question come from? Context please

@Mike It's from a math book from my country, idk if the explicit name would help because is in my natal language...

Why the vote to close the post?

You already proved that if the pyramid has $2$ lateral sides congruent, then the intersection of planes $(VMC),(VNA),(VPB)$ is the line.
In the following, let us prove that if the intersection of planes $(VMC),(VNA),(VPB)$ is the line, then the pyramid has $2$ lateral sides congruent.
Proof :
Let
$VA=a,VB=b,VC=c$
$AB=BC=CA=d$
$AM=e,BN=f,CP=g$
Since the intersection of planes $(VMC),(VNA),(VPB)$ is the line, we have
$$\frac{NC}{BN}\cdot\frac{MB}{AM}\cdot\frac{PA}{CP}=1$$
i.e.
$$efg=(d-g)(d-e)(d-f)\tag1$$
Since
$$VM^2=b^2-(d-e)^2=a^2-e^2$$
$$VN^2=b^2-f^2=c^2-(d-f)^2$$
$$VP^2=a^2-(d-g)^2=c^2-g^2$$
we have
$$e=\frac{a^2-b^2+d^2}{2d}\tag2$$
$$f=\frac{b^2-c^2+d^2}{2d}\tag3$$
$$g=\frac{c^2-a^2+d^2}{2d}\tag4$$
It follows from $(1)(2)(3)(4)$ that
$$(a^2-b^2+d^2)(b^2-c^2+d^2)(c^2-a^2+d^2)-(d^2-c^2+a^2)(d^2-a^2+b^2)(d^2-b^2+c^2)=0$$
i.e.
$$2(- a^4 b^2 +  a^4 c^2 +  a^2 b^4 -  a^2 c^4 -  b^4 c^2 +  b^2 c^4)=0$$
This can be written as
$$2(a^2-b^2)(b^2-c^2)(c^2-a^2)=0$$
which is equivalent to
$$(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)=0$$
Therefore, we can say that the pyramid has $2$ lateral sides congruent.$\ \blacksquare$
